# How do I force terraform to recreate a resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lightsail

I have two resources:

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance" "myserver-sig" {
  name              = "myserver-Sig"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
  blueprint_id      = "ubuntu_20_04"
  bundle_id         = "nano_2_0"
  key_pair_name     = "LightsailDefaultKeyPair"
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports" "myserver-sig-public-ports" {
  instance_name = aws_lightsail_instance.myserver-sig.name
  port_info {
    protocol  = "tcp"
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
  }
  port_info {
    protocol  = "tcp"
    from_port = 80
    to_port   = 80
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_lightsail_instance.myserver-sig,
  ]
}
```

When I first run `terraform apply` both resources are created.

If I want to replace the `aws_lightsail_instance` with a new version then the `aws_lightsail_instance` will redeploy, but the `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports` will not because the ports haven't changed.

However as part of the deploy of `aws_lightsail_instance` it changes the public ports to close 443 and open 22. This means that the end state of the redeploy of the `aws_lightsail_instance` is that port 443 is closed.

If I run `terraform apply` again then it will correctly replace `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports` opening port 443

How do I force a recreation of the `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports` resource so that I only have to run `terraform apply` once?

Comment: Are you the only one running this code? Is there state file locking implemented?

Comment: I'm the only one running this code. It's the lightsail instance itself that starts with default ports open. Whenever you recreate a lightsail instance you always need to reconfigure the ports. This means that you can't lock the state to stop the instance from opening and closing it's own ports.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the AWS Terraform provider that you should submit to them. In the mean time running `apply` twice is probably the best option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle [`replace_triggered_by`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#replace_triggered_by) attribute to do this. This was introduced in Terraform 1.2.0 (released May 2022).

In your case to trigger the replace of `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports.myserver-sig-public-ports` whenever `aws_lightsail_instance.myserver-sig` is replaced, add the following code to the  `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports.myserver-sig-public-ports` configuration:

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports" "myserver-sig-public-ports" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      aws_lightsail_instance.myserver-sig.id
    ]
  }
}
```

Thus, whenever the Lightsail instance is replaced, the public ports will automatically be triggered to be replaced.

If you want to always replace the public ports, even when the Lightsail instance has not been, replaced add this configuration:

```
resource "null_resource" "always_run" {
  triggers = {
    timestamp = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports" "myserver-sig-public-ports" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      null_resource.always_run
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can force the recreation (delete/create or -/+) by using the `-replace=ADDRESS` argument with `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`:

```
terraform apply -replace=aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports.myserver-sig-public-ports
```

This replaces the former workflow of `terraform taint <resource_address>` followed by a `plan` and `apply`. If you are using an older version of Terraform, then you would need to use `taint` instead:

```
terraform taint aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports.myserver-sig-public-ports
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in main.tf? I just want to run `terraform apply`

Comment: @UEFI How about adding new resource "aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports" "myserver-sig-public-ports-**new**" and comment the old one?

Comment: @UEFI My answer satisfies both of those. You are already doing it in the config containing the resource, and you are executing a `terraform apply`.

Comment: I want to execute `terraform apply` without any unusual arguments. I want a "one click" deployment where engineers don't have to think about odd edge cases. If I make that terraform command the new normal way of deploying then gradually more things will get added to the terraform command and in a year or two it'll be someone's job to know all of the edge cases required to deploy our infrastructure.

Comment: @UEFI I think you can comment out the resource in main.tf, apply it to destroy the resource, then uncomment and apply again to re-create it.

Comment: While this all may work technically, I totally agree with @UEFI that it's a non-satisfying solution to explicitly having to specify the resource name within the apply command, to trigger a recreation. There should be a "force_recreation" flag, or list option somewhere, that can be filled with terraform resources, which on apply should be deleted first, before doing the usual reconciliation.

Comment: The taint way is probably still better than -replace as you can do that without having to modify the apply command.